# Blazor: How to pass a parameter via URL to the ViewModel (not to the page/view)

Tags: mvvm, blazor, url-parameters

I know how to pass a parameter from the url to a blazor page like this:

```
@page "/myPage/{myParameter}"

@if(myParameter != null && myParameter != "")
{
  <p>@myParameter</p>
}

@code{
  [Parameter]
  public string myParameter {get; set;};
}
```

If I would enter something like this in the browser: [www.xyz.com/mypage/TEST](http://www.xyz.com/mypage/TEST)
I could show 'TEST' on my page. But how can I pass a parameter directly to my injected ViewModel?

This doesn't work `@page "/mypage/{ViewModel.myParameter}"`. The ViewModel is injected via Startup.cs and as a services.AddScoped.

I have a 'workaround':

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string myParameter { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized() //On Page Load
    {
        ViewModel.myParameter = myParameter;
    }
}
```

Is there a proper way to do this? Thx for help (still new to blazor)

Comment: You might try using the ViewModel as a backing property to your [Parameter]... `{ get => ViewModel.myParameter; set => ViewModel.myParameter = value; } ` I _think _ ViewModel should be injected already.

Comment: @jhr Sorry I don't understand what I should try. Where shall I put the 'backing property...' in the ViewModel.cs or in the View.razor @Code{...}? I would love to leave the hole @code{...} block blank as a true View-File with no code.

Comment: Till now I always used @bind in the editform in the View to get data to the ViewModel but this time I don't have a place to make that binding, because I don't use Userinput from the page. The only info that I want to pass is the Url-Parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyParameter` is extracted from the Route by the Router and passed into the page component as a Parameter in `SetParametersAsync`.  In theory you could put in on the setter for `myParameter`.  **Don't - this is very definitely not recommended practice**.

Also, Lets say you're on "/mypage/1" and you navigate to "/mypage/2", `OnInitialized` won't be called.  You may think you're navigating between pages, but in reality, your just calling `SetParametersAsync` on the same component with a new value for `MyParameter`.

Therefore something like:

```
    protected override void OnParametersSet() 
    {
        if (!ViewModel.myParameter.Equals(myParameter)) ViewModel.myParameter = myParameter;
    }
```

will ensure it is set if it changes, otherwise not (I don't know what getters/setters are on `myParameter` and what setting it every time on `OnParametersSet` precipitates!).

Comment: Shaun: It is then  impossible to leave the 'view.razor'-Page completly blank of any C# Code (besides the @inject MyViewModelService ViewModel)? And get the url-parameter  to the ViewModel? And if I wanted to  use that parameter in the viewModel. I should use  OnParameterSet from inside the view.razor-page? Did I understand that correct?

Comment: Basically correct.  You could 1. Put the code in a code-behind file  2. If you use the same `myParameter` on multiple pages build `MyParameterComponentBase` and then inherit.